# To send threekeys using send_keys() in selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to type a float number  into a textbox with default value 0.00.But it tries to get appended instead of overwriting it.I tried with .clear() and then send_keys('123.00') but still it gets appended. 
Then i tried with send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a','123.00').It updates 0.00 only.

Any help is really appreciated.

For more info ..
URL : http://new.ossmoketest.appspot.com
userid: senthil.arumugam@mycompanyname.com  -- mycompanyname = orangescape  (sorry to avoid spam mails)
password not needed now.
click purchaseorder... in the form please new product and new price... sample application for automation.. thanks

Comment: Add much more of the actual code into your question

Comment: atlast i found the answer... send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a'+Keys.NULL, str(newprice))

Answer (score 20):

I've had good results with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
element.send_keys('123.00')
```

If that doesn't work it may have something to do with the code in the web page.

Comment: @Miebster Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Unless you have custom editbox, `click()` should work for you:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

b = Firefox()
b.get('http://google.com')
e = b.find_element_by_id('lst-ib')

e.click()  # is optional, but makes sure the focus is on editbox.
e.send_keys('12.34')
e.get_attribute('value')
# outputs: u'12.34'

e.click()
e.clear()
e.get_attribute('value')
# outputs: u''

e.send_keys('56.78')
e.get_attribute('value')
# outputs: u'56.78'
```

Answer (score 4):

I just found the **clear()** command - see [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#clear%28%29):

If this element is a text entry element, this will clear the value. Has no effect on other elements. Text entry elements are INPUT and TEXTAREA elements.

**EDIT:**
So your approach would be:

```
   element.clear();
   element.sendKeys('123.00');
```

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced issues with all the examples given in other answers.

```
el.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a' + Keys.NULL, 'your string')
```

Has worked in all the projects I've worked in, so much I've wrapped it into my own implementation of the Webdriver class with more robust operations.